# 4D LSTM: Trouble with I/O Shapes

Tags: python, keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I'm trying to get a 4D TimeDistributed(LSTM(...)) to work in Keras, but I'm having a problem with the input/output shapes.

```
batch_size = 1

model = Sequential()

model.add(TimeDistributed(LSTM(7, batch_input_shape=(batch_size,
    look_back,dataset.shape[1], dataset.shape[2]), stateful=True,
    return_sequences=True), batch_input_shape=(batch_size,
    look_back, dataset.shape[1], dataset.shape[2])))

model.add(TimeDistributed(LSTM(7, batch_input_shape= (batch_size,
    look_back,dataset.shape[1],dataset.shape[2]),
    stateful=True), batch_input_shape=(batch_size, look_back,
    dataset.shape[1], dataset.shape[2])))

model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(7, input_shape = (batch_size,
   1,look_back, dataset.shape[1],dataset.shape[2]))))

model.compile(loss = 'mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')

for i in range(10):
    model.fit(trainX, trainY, epochs=1, batch_size=batch_size,
        verbose=2, shuffle=False)
    model.reset_states()
```

The input shapes for trainX, trainY, and dataset are as follows:

> trainX.shape = (63, 3, 34607, 7)
>   trainY.shape = (63, 34607, 7)
>   dataset.shape = (100, 34607, 7)

The errors I am receiving are as follows:

> Error when checking target: expected time_distributed_59 to  have
>   shape (1, 3, 7) but got array with shape (63, 34607, 7)

The above layer mentioned is regarding the last TimeDistributed Dense Layer.

Here is the output when I print out the input and output shape of each layer:

> (1, 3, 34607, 7) layer[0] - Input
>   (1, 3, 34607, 7) layer[0] - Output
>   (1, 3, 34607, 7) layer[1] - Input
>   (1, 3, 7) layer[1] - Output
>   (1, 3, 7) layer[2] - Input
>   (1, 3, 7) layer[2] - Output

However, the final output layer should be a prediction with shape (1, 1, 34067, 7) or shape (1, 34067, 7)

Thank you for any suggestions!

Comment: Could you elaborate more on what do you actually want to achievie? This seems to be a really weird problem and architecture you use seems to be inappropriate.

Comment: @MarcinMożejko I have a training set X that includes { [ t_1, t_2, t_3 ] , [ t_2, t_3, t_4] , [ t_3, t_4, t_5 ] ... } such that 't_i' is the i-th tilmestep which is a 3-D vector. 

Also, I have training set Y that includes [ t_4, t_5, t_6 ... ]. Thus, I am using an LSTM to learn the mapping from X_n to Y_n such that n is the corresponding index to each vector, X and Y.

Comment: @MarcinMożejko More abstractly, I want to use an LSTM for regression of multiple lab results of many patients across time.

Comment: From what I've read, I have to use TimeDistributed to input 4D vectors into an LSTM.

Comment: @MarcinMożejko Did this explanation help?

Answer (score 2):

You didn't set return sequences = True on your second Time Distributed LSTM layer; default is false. This would explain the (1,3,7) output shape you're getting.